# Is there any point in answering a question when there is already a better answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

There are some cases when you get to a question that already has a similar answer to the one that you thought you would give. Should you answer anyway? Reinforce the best answer with comments?

What if you have extra details to support the answer? Would it be best to add them as a comment to the best answer?

Comment: It might help if you said why you'd want to do this. My gut reaction is "no, why would you possibly do that?" but I'm assuming there's a reason you're considering this. Are you suggesting your answer is not as good, but different; i.e. adds some extra (but less important) detail. If you just agree with the answer up vote it

Comment: @Jon Only do that if you add some additional value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, if you have nothing useful to contribute to a post, you shouldn't post a useless answer anyway.

If you have a relevant clarification to add in a comment, then sure, add a comment.  If you have nothing to add, or request clarification of, for the post, then no, you shouldn't be commenting just for its own sake.

Comment: it's always good to upvote if you think an existing answer is great.